# How to change font size by adb command

Tags: android, adb, accessibility

Is there an ADB command to change the devices font size?

I want to be able to change the font to any one of the options found in the UI (`small`, `medium`, `huge`)

Answer (score 26):

Working method to change the font scale (Tested on android 7.1.1):

```
adb shell settings put system font_scale {float_representing_the_scale}
```

The font scales that are presented in the settings application:
(as per android 10)

- Small - 0.85
- Default - 1.0
- Large - 1.15
- Largest - 1.30

Comment: Correct answer, but how did you find that out?

Comment: @rekire I found in the android source code. I don't remember the details exactly - but I probably found it in the "settings" application code

Comment: Cool, I guess you don't remember the link right now, but for the future answers it would be nice to provide the source too.

Comment: You can display a list of all the settings with `adb shell settings list system`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:
adb shell wm density 300

Comment: Hi Nitesh, this command works. but i need to toggle between the predefined fontssize in settigs page  such as Medium, Huge, Large